# Is it necessary to shuffle x coordinates in Latin Hypercube Sampling (LHC)?

Tags: sampling, latin-hypercube

I am dealing with some implementations details about LHC sampling and I found that the common algorithm is as follows:

1. Determine the limits for each cell (row/column)
2. Sample a random number in each cell for each axis
3. Shuffle the values for the y axis
4. Shuffle the values for the x axis

As I see it, it should only be necessary to shuffle either x or y but not both. Is my intuition right?

Moreover, does it has any relation with Orthogonal sampling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of shuffling at the end, you can also randomly permute the cells in the beginning.  I agree that with only two variables, it is not necessary to "shuffle" them both, however, with multiple variables, the cells are normally determined by a random permutation of the margins.

Take a look at the `lhs` package in R which I maintain:  [here](https://bertcarnell.github.io/lhs/) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lhs).  Basically, I take a random permutation of the grid cells first, then sample within the cell on the right portion of a uniform [0,1], then finally transform that margin to the desired distribution (normal, lognormal, etc).

Here is an example:

```
> require(lhs)
> 
> set.seed(1976)
> 
> n <- 10 # number of points
> k <- 3 # number of variables
> 
> X <- lhs::randomLHS(n, k)
> X
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,] 0.2680391 0.90984671 0.32282714
 [2,] 0.4650695 0.60968382 0.52804701
 [3,] 0.7627429 0.19106196 0.95160616
 [4,] 0.1613597 0.23806651 0.16208844
 [5,] 0.8526418 0.42502816 0.63481989
 [6,] 0.6657381 0.01009047 0.74752755
 [7,] 0.9751648 0.31506482 0.43636882
 [8,] 0.5882519 0.70313117 0.03205706
 [9,] 0.0850597 0.82383767 0.24122074
[10,] 0.3730471 0.58030863 0.85381532
> 
> # notice the grid cells
> floor(n*X) + 1
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    3   10    4
 [2,]    5    7    6
 [3,]    8    2   10
 [4,]    2    3    2
 [5,]    9    5    7
 [6,]    7    1    8
 [7,]   10    4    5
 [8,]    6    8    1
 [9,]    1    9    3
[10,]    4    6    9
> 
> Y <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = k)
> Y[,1] <- qnorm(X[,1], 3, 2)
> Y[,2] <- qlnorm(X[,2], 1, 1)
> Y[,3] <- qunif(X[,3], -1, 1)
> 
> Y
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
 [1,] 1.7624913 10.3792816 -0.35434573
 [2,] 2.8246599  3.5912311  0.05609402
 [3,] 4.4303070  1.1342940  0.90321232
 [4,] 1.0222298  1.3330428 -0.67582313
 [5,] 5.0956622  2.2500522  0.26963979
 [6,] 3.8563497  0.2663439  0.49505510
 [7,] 6.9255817  1.6794320 -0.12726236
 [8,] 3.4461011  4.6340330 -0.93588589
 [9,] 0.2563595  6.8901281 -0.51755852
[10,] 2.3524128  3.3290371  0.70763064
```

I'm not sure what you mean by orthogonal sampling, but Latin hypercube samples are related to Orthogonal Arrays as you can see in the package as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then my question would be, it is really necessary to shuffle all variables or we can simply shuffle all but one? If we have n variables, can we just simply shuffle n-1?

Orthogonal Sampling is an special case of LHC where each subspace is sampled evenly - See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41725/291498

Comment: Yes, you only need to shuffle all but one column.  On the question of "Orthogonal Sampling": it is a term that I have not seen used in any literature.  Notice that the citations on the Wikipedia page do not refer to "orthogonal sampling".  Instead, as I alluded to in my answer, they are orthogonal array Latin hypercube samples.  The references for those are in the "further reading" section.  They are also used in the R package I referenced.  The process for drawing an orthogonal array Latin hypercube sample is more complicated and starts with creating an orthogonal array.

Comment: Thanks for all the details, is it possible to use this R package to generate Progressive Orthogonal LHCs?

Comment: You are welcome.  The R package has a function to add further samples to the LHC given a base design which is the foundation of the progressive LHC.  The function is called augmentLHS.  I have not spent enough time with this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315600370_Progressive_Latin_Hypercube_Sampling_An_efficient_approach_for_robust_sampling-based_analysis_of_environmental_models) to know if the augmentLHS function with a based orthogonal array LHC would be equivalent.  The authors seem to be making a few additional claims beyond the package capabilities.